# How to calculate the slope in percentage of linearly fitted data in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I hope someone can help me.

Lets say I have the following two vectors

```
t =  [1 2 3 4 5];
m = [10 8 6 4 2];
plot(t,m)
```

And I want to find the slope of the linear fit (1. degree)

so I write:

```
polyfit(t,m,1)
```

I then obtain the following answer:
ans =

```
-2.0000   12.0000
```

Meaning that `y = -2x + 12`

How do I re-calculate the coefficient to a percentage slope?

The reason I am interested in this is that I want to discard all data that has a slope < 80% (and proceed with data with slope coefficients between 80% and 100%).

Comment: What do you mean by percentage slope? Is it #2 from this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grade_%28slope%29#Nomenclature? Because that percentage goes from 0 to infinity...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you define percentage slope by the formula given in #2 of the [Nopmenclature section on the Wikipedia Grade page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grade_%28slope%29#Nomenclature), `100 * dy / dx`, your percentage slope is just the coefficient of `x^1`, multiplied by 100. You can do a test to check for slopes < 80% as follows:

```
t =  [1 2 3 4 5];
m = [10 8 6 4 2];
p = polyfit(t,m,1);
g = p(1) * 100;
if g > 80 && g < 100
    % Do what you need to do...
end
```

Comment: Yes, when I say percentage slope I mean as in #2 from this: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grade_%28slope%29#Nomenclature.

It says the the percentage can expressed as the tangent of the angle of inclination times 100. 

So that:
t =  [1 2 3 4 5];
m = [10 8 6 4 2];
p = polyfit(t,m,1);
slope = p(1);
angle= atand(slope); 
percentage_slope= 100*tan(angle)

This gives a percentage slope of 68.8691 % in this example.


If I just say p(1)*100, then I get 200 %, which I dont really think make sense if you look at the figure. plot(t,m)


So what do you think is right?

Thank you

Comment: @user3151758. The section does not mention tangents or angles at all. The percentage is given as 100 * rise / run, or just 100 * the slope of the line. A grade of 200% means that the slope is 2. Keep in mind that the formula `tan(atand(x))` is pretty much meaningless since `atand` returns something in degrees while `tan` takes an argument in radians. Note that your data has a slope of `-8/4 = -2`, and that `tan(atan(x))` just returns `x` up to a difference of sign.

Comment: @user3151758. Are you trying to get a percentage like `100 * abs(atand(p(1))) / 90`? This would be the angular percentage of the absolute value of the slope.